# Что означает оператор << в C#?

Tags: c#, enum

В определении перечисления используется символ `<<`:

```
public enum Lights
{
    NormalLights = 1 << 0,
    Highbeams = 1 << 10,
}
```

Что он означает и для чего он используется?

Comment: [Оператор << (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator)

Comment: @Grundy в дубликате нет прямого ответа на этот вопрос, к сожалению

Comment: @defaultlocale, на самом деле есть, там просто сам вопрос немного шире. Но работа оператора сдвига вполне описана.

Comment: @Grundy «немного» это мягко сказано :) В вопросе по ссылке нет: описания работы оператора, ссылки на документацию, релевантных примеров. Для сравнения такой же вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007526/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Оператор сдвига влево (<<) сдвигает первый операнд влево на число битов, задаваемое вторым операндом. Второй операнд должен иметь тип int или тип, для которого существует предварительно определенное неявное числовое преобразование в int. (Подробнее как советовал @Grundy почитайте [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator), определение оттуда)

Примеры для понимания сути оператора:

```
Console.WriteLine("1 << 1 = " + (1 << 1));
Console.WriteLine("1 << 2 = " + (1 << 2));
Console.WriteLine("1 << 3 = " + (1 << 3));
```

В ответ даст следующее:

```
1 << 1 = 2
1 << 2 = 4
1 << 3 = 8
```

Что же такое сдвиг:

При применении оператора << Вы сдвигаете все число влево на заданное число бит, т.е.

1. 000000001 << 2 = 000000100
   в результате 1 оказывается на 3 месте и при расшифровке инта система получает 8
2. 000001011 << 5 = 101100000
   в результате 11 перетекает в 704

В Вашем случае Вы сдвигаете

```
public enum Lights
{
    NormalLights = 1 << 0, // т.е. 1 сдвигаем на 0
    Highbeams = 1 << 10, // т.е. 1 сдвигаем на 10
}
```

итого это равносильно

```
public enum Lights
{
    NormalLights = 1
    Highbeams = 1024
}
```

Хотя в целом я не понимаю логики заведения enum таким способом. Компилятор поставит уже вычисленные значения.

Comment: Добавил ответом, потому как на основе [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/company/Voximplant/blog/266305/) делаю предположение, что не все найдут ответ в вопросе без ответа с галочкой.

Comment: Все нормально, но думаю стоит добавить явно определение `<<` в текст ответа. Сейчас ответ на заданный вопрос дается только по ссылке, а это неудобно.

Comment: Вот так наверно лучше

Comment: _Хотя в целом я не понимаю логики заведения enum таким способом._ - для флагов бывает намного удобнее проставить таким образом чем думать был ли уже выставлен этот бит или нет:  `1<<0`, `1<<1`, `1<<2`, `1<<3`, `1<<4` вместо: `1`,`2`,`4`,`8`, `16`

Comment: Спасибо - буду знать